# Need help structuring the chromosome for genetic algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetic

I need to design a time table problem using genetic algorithm. Parameters for the problem are:
Teachers:8
Subject:16
Class Rooms:4
Days:5
Slots:5

What should the chromosome structure be?

Comment: Your chromosome structure should be a 5x5 array. As the purpose of your genetic algorithm is to fill this timetable. However a lot of information is missing here. How many classes are there (there don't seem to be any students). And what exactly are you trying to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

*Full disclosure, this answer references my own npm package.  I will though try and make my answer as generic as possible.*

If we used something like [geneticalgorithm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geneticalgorithm) to solve the problem, you would need to implement the following :

1. fitness Function
2. mutation Function
3. crossover Function
4. diversity Function (or doesABeatBFunction)

Your question really spans all 4 functions.  Let's imagine your chromosome function is just plain old JSON and walk through each function and discuss.

## Fitness Function

Can a fitness function process JSON?  Sure, you can do that.  If the JSON is not a valid schedule you can just assign it a fitness of zero.  If you can somehow rate 1 invalid schedule as being better than another, then even better.

## Mutation Function

Can you code a mutation function for you JSON?  Yes.  Switch 2 teachers around, or days or class rooms.  It doesn't have to create valid children (but that may be a plus)

## Crossover Function

This could be tricky no matter the format.  After you get the mutation function done and can see that your algorithm actually evolves better answers then work on crossover.  Crossover can mean *take part of the answer from one parent and part of the answer from another*.  With that in mind, you could use the teacher from one, and the class rooms from the other.  The Crossover doesn't have to cover every possible data encoding for it to be very useful.  Implement this in stages and test it independently of the genetic algorithm.

## Diversity Function

Can you measure if two JSON configs are similar or different?  This should be fairly straight forward.  Checking each node in the JSON to see if it is equal would be a reasonable first implementation.

## Conclusion

I believe your chromosome structure can be nearly anything so long as you can imagine how to implement the above functions.  I proposed JSON because it isn't so much a structure but a way of storing nearly any structure just to prove the point.

The core of a genetic algorithm depends on the implementation of the above functions and is independent of chromosome.  Only your function implementations have to work with the chromosome.

Cheers!